# Proof that increasing function implies nonnegative derivative

Tags: real-analysis

In my textbook they give the proof that a positive derivative implies an increasing function. Then they state this lemma (the converse)[image: (see picture)] but give no proof. I was wondering if anyone could guide me in the right direction. All the proofs I have tried just seem like a copy of the original proof that the positive derivative implies an increasing function. However, I don't believe that is a really satisfying answer - seems rather recursive.

This is what I've come to:

Let $ \epsilon = g'(t_0)$. Then there exists a neighborhood $N$ of $t_0$ s.t. for $t \in N$ and $ t \ne t_0$ we have that 
$|\frac {g(b)-g(a)}{(b-a)} -g'(t_0)| < g'(t_0)$
so 
$\frac {g(b)-g(a)}{(b-a)}$ is positive for $t \in N$, $ t \ne t_0$.

Comment: If $g'(t)<0$ for some $t\in(a,b)$ you should be able to show $g$ is not increasing near $t$, by using the definition of differentiability of $g$ at $t$.

Comment: Fix $t \in (a,b)$. For a small positive $h$, $g(t+h) \geq g(t)$ since $g$ is increasing. Can you rearrange this to say something about the derivative?

Comment: I was thinking of using the definition of the derivative and showing that for $\epsilon > 0$ we have that $g' (t) > -\epsilon$. However, I am not entirely sure this would work.

Comment: Let $c \in(a, b) $. Can you see that if $f$ is increasing then the ratio $(f(x) - f(c)) /(x-c) $ is non-negative?

Answer (score 2):

If $h>0$, we have for $t\in (a,b)$,
$$
g(t+h)-g(t)\geq 0\implies\frac{g(t+h)-g(t)}{h}\geq 0
$$
So 
$$
\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{g(t+h)-g(t)}{h}\geq 0
$$
Similarly, for $h<0$ we have 
$$
g(t+h)-g(t)\leq 0\implies\frac{g(t+h)-g(t)}{h}\geq 0
$$
so 
$$
\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{g(t+h)-g(t)}{h}\geq 0
$$
and finally 
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(t+h)-g(t)}{h}=g'(t)\geq 0
$$